# The content of directory /dev/fd have difference file in one time

Tags: directory-structure

I have such command.

```
#echo -e "ls\npwd" >test
#bash
#exec <test
```

After this code.You will find

```
#ls /dev/fd
```

> `0  1  2  3`

```
#cd /dev/fd;ls
```

> `0  1  2  255`

Fun,the directory `/dev/fd` have difference content..What's happen?

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/fd` is not a fixed directory, but a symlink that points to a directory on a per-process basis.  In your two invocations of `ls`, you are listing the contents of two different "directories".

Your first output gives the file descriptors associated with `ls`.  The second output gives the file descriptors associated with `bash`.  The `echo` and `exec` preceding the directory listings do not change this.

Consider:

```
foo:~$ ls -ln /dev/fd/
total 0
lrwx------ 1 1000 1000 64 Jul 10 12:13 0 -> /dev/pts/19
lrwx------ 1 1000 1000 64 Jul 10 12:13 1 -> /dev/pts/19
lrwx------ 1 1000 1000 64 Jul 10 12:13 2 -> /dev/pts/19
lr-x------ 1 1000 1000 64 Jul 10 12:13 3 -> /proc/20115/fd
foo:~$ cat /dev/fd/../cmdline && echo
cat/dev/fd/../cmdline

foo:~$ cd /dev/fd ; ls -ln
total 0
lrwx------ 1 1000 1000 64 Jul  8 05:01 0 -> /dev/pts/19
lrwx------ 1 1000 1000 64 Jul  8 05:01 1 -> /dev/pts/19
lrwx------ 1 1000 1000 64 Jul  8 05:01 2 -> /dev/pts/19
lrwx------ 1 1000 1000 64 Jul  8 05:01 255 -> /dev/pts/19
foo:/dev/fd$ cat ../cmdline && echo
bash
foo:/dev/fd$ pwd -P
/proc/2689/fd
```

Comment: I'm sorry,I need some time to go through.

Comment: @yode keep in mind that the `/proc`, `/dev`, and `/sys` filesystems are not disk files, but interfaces to kernel and OS data via a file-like interface, for a gross simplification.